# Issues with brightness on Lenovo Legion 5 brightness (with Intel + NVIDIA)

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics, lenovo, brightness

I have Lenovo Legion 5 (i7 + 1660 Ti). All works fine, but brightness control doesn't work at all. I've tried all fixes from forums and can't solve this problem. The last kernel didn't fix this problem. Also, I tried last Ubuntu 21, Kubuntu, Pop!_OS - everywhere is the same problem.
What I need - turn on intel graphics and turn off Nvidia (so in BIOS need to be hybrid mode). I saw many fixes for AMD graphics, but not for intel. Any ideas?

By the way

1. If I enable in BIOS Hybrid mode - I have the same brightness as in Windows by default in Ubuntu, without can't changing
2. If I enable in BIOS Discrete mode - I have 100% brightness in Ubuntu, without can't changing

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers > Use Nvidia X Server Settings to switch profiles > Reboot. There's nothing else. Whether is solves the brightness issue is probably a long shot. Still proprietary drivers are recommended but brightness control sometimes require hardware specific additional boot parameters. What exactly have you been trying?

Comment: @ChanganAuto nvidia drivers installed last 460. no working control brightness. i`ve tried anything (acpi_backlight=vendor, video, intel, amdgpu.backlight=0, etc). also i`ve tried install last kernels - nothing. i want to enable hybrid mode in bios and then enable only intel gpu in ubuntu, but with working control backlight.

Answer (score 2):

have Lenovo Legion 5(Ryzen7 + RTX3060), using Pop!_OS 20.04, faced same problem.

I prefer to work on discrete card, so solved it with:

```
sudo kernelstub -a "nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

After reboot my brightness control buttons started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue using the proprietary Nvidia drivers (in my case, the nvidia-driver-510), on the Lenovo Legion 5 running Ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I switched to the X.org open source driver, the brightness control worked, but my computer then could not suspend; the computer would instead get stuck on a blank screen and not move forwards.

I also noticed that the NVIDIA X SERVER program was coming up blank whenever I tried to open it.

Eventually, this lead me to [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1394120/541523), which provided a solution (in a comment, naturally) to all of the Nvidia X Server issue, the suspend issue, and the brightness issue:
Remove all the nvidia drivers and reinstall them.

I ran this command:

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia*
```

Which removed all of the nvidia content on my computer; and then ran

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

which reinstalled the drivers, properly this time. I rebooted the computer and everything worked.

(This was after hours of trying to adjust grub settings, adding things in, adjusting things... none of that helped, but reinstalling the drivers worked in about three minutes. Should have just tried that at the start.)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fully FIXED in Linux kernel 5.16.0 (tested in Ubuntu 21.10 with liquorix kernel).

Details: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1671